# Keep getting Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, only with some users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, oauth

I am using the Twitter gem at (https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter). Keep getting Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, only with some users. For other users, the request is fulfilled without any problems.

```
user = User.first
client = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').first.token, :oauth_token_secret => user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').first.secret)
client.follower_ids
```

The exact error: `Twitter::Error::Unauthorized: This method requires authentication.`

This happens on a case to case basis. The problem affects a number of users on our system. The first thing you might think, is that their `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` might be invalid. I am storing these tokens the same way I am storing the tokens for every user. So there is no reason to suspect that the tokens may be invalid.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure they allowed your app during the OAuth process?  They could have pressed "Deny" instead.

Comment: I don't think he would have gotten a token/secret in that case.  It's possible that the users have deauthorized the application, though, which would invalidate the credentials.  Are the users themselves complaining?

Comment: Yeap, the users are the ones complaining

Comment: they haven't somehow set their tweets to private and this has had an affect?

Comment: Nah, I can see their tweets on Twitter, even if I am not a follower

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I have the same problem...

Comment: Sorry none as of yet, have you @MichaelKoper ?

Comment: Try to roll back a version or two. See the commits. Have had same kind of issue with omniauth2. Maybe it is a CSRF token issue(missing CSRF)..

Comment: The gem is totally deleted..

Comment: Close question due to gem is removed..

Comment: What gem is totally deleted?

Comment: Yes @ChristianFazzini I will post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

The `Could not authenticate with OAuth` error means the `oauth_token` and `oauth_secret` are no longer valid.

Earlier today we had some similar reports saying the values copied directly from the *Your access token* section of this site were not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came with a silly solution. The twitter API changed and you need your oauth_token and your oauth_token_secret(even though you post with somebody else their token). You have to generate them in the twitter developer page. Kind of double.... But it worked for me.

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'key'
  config.consumer_secret = 'secret'
  config.oauth_token = 'oauth_token'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'oauth_token_secret'
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wouldn't this do calls on your account instead of the client's? Do you have a link to the API changes that you describe?